# webapi 2 bind model from json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2, modelbinders

I need to bind model from request and convert to my custom object, my request data is json and method is post.

This is my method in web api:

```
public IHttpActionResult Edit([ModelBinder(typeof(KModelBinder))] object data)
```

My problem is: I cannot access to json from `ValueProvider` in modelbinder.

```
public class KModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        var valueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider;
        var valProviderResult = valueProvider.GetValue("id");
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: if i dont use json, modelbinder detect data, but whene request is json, modelbinder cannot detect data :(

Comment: Did you tried like this: `public IHttpActionResult Edit(MyModelClass data)`? It should work out of the box.

Comment: no! because, this method use for multi models, and i detect model in model binder

Comment: Why not create a base controller and inherit to other controllers from that base controller. You can make it generic and implement the `Edit` method like this `public IHttpActionResult Edit(T data)`. If you need more info I'll post it as an aswer.

Comment: @MihailStancescu please send more info, thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a base controller class like this

```
public class BaseController<T>: ApiController
{

    //here you can add whatever dependency injection you may use
    public BaseController(DbContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;  
    }

   [HttpPost]
   public IHttpActionResult Add(T data)
   {
       return Ok(_context.Add(data));
   }

   [HttpPut]
   public IHttpActionResult Edit(T data)
   {
        _context.Modify(data); //here depends on your ORM or data access layer
        return Ok(data);
   }

   /*other methods you think are necessary in this base controller*/
}
```

Afterwards you can define your controllers like this

```
public class UserController: BaseController<User>
{
   //here you can override the base controller methods
}
```

I use somewhat similarly approach in my current project and works fine.

Check it out and see if this works for your project.